# Making assumption in natural deduction proof

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, natural-deduction

I read in a textbook the proof for $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r) \vdash (p \wedge q) \rightarrow r$ is like this:

$1.\hspace{10mm} p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r) \hspace{10mm}\text{premise}$

$2.\hspace{20mm} p \wedge q \hspace{13mm}\text{assumption}$

$3.\hspace{20mm} p \hspace{20mm}\text{∧-elim}_{1}\text{ 2}$

$4.\hspace{20mm} q \hspace{20mm}\text{∧-elim}_{2}\text{ 2}$

$5.\hspace{20mm} q \rightarrow r \hspace{11.5mm}\text{→-elim}\text{ 1, 3}$

$6.\hspace{20mm} r \hspace{20.5mm}\text{→-elim}\text{ 5, 4}$

$7.\hspace{10mm} (p \wedge q) \rightarrow r \hspace{12mm}\text{→-intro}\text{ 2-6}$

My question is why was the assumption $p \wedge q$ made? Rather if I assumed $p$ and $q$, then couldn't I do a conjunction introduction in next line?

$p \hspace{10mm}\text{assumption}$

$q \hspace{10mm}\text{assumption}$

$p \wedge q \hspace{10mm}\text{∧-intro}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of **conditional introduction** ($\to\!\mathsf i$) discharges the *assumption* and makes it the *antecedent* for the conditional statement.   Meanwhile the *conclusion* derived within the context of *that assumption* becomes the *consequent* of the conditional statement.

So if you *want* to deduce $(p\land q)\to r$ using this rule, you are *required* to assume the antecedent ($p\land q$) aiming to derive the consequent ($r$).

Deriving $p\land q$ along the way from *some other assumptions* will not set things up for you to apply the rule and deduce the desired conditional.   Deriving $r$ under assumptions of $p$ and then $q$ will only allow you to deduce $p\to (q\to r)$ which, being the premise itself, is unremarkable.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{p\to(q\to r)}{\fitch{\color{blue}{p\land q}}{q\\p\\q\to r\\\color{red}r}\\\color{blue}{(p\land q)}\to\color{red} r}\qquad\fitch{p\to(q\to r)}{\fitch{p}{\fitch q{p\land q\\p\\q\to r\\r}\\q\to r}\\p\to(q\to r)}$$

Answer (score 1):

You don't get to assume $p$, nor do you get to assume $q$.  The statement to be proven is $(p\wedge q) \rightarrow \cdots$ so what you get to assume in the proof is $(p\wedge q)$.  Yes, from that you can deduce $p$ (and also you can deduce $q$) but in a proof this needs to be justified, which is what the text proof does.